# Docker-compose creates a fresh db every time, data is not saved

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am doing some local WP development. Every time I make changes (like add a plugin)

and run: `docker-compose up -d && docker-compose logs -f wordpress`

It creates a fresh db and the plugins get deleted a long with any changes. I can export a `.wp` file with all in one migration plugin everytime, and import it again, but what is a better way?

Comment: Supply your docker-compose.yml if possible

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to supply it, can you kindly point me in the direction of what I should look for ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [top-level volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) in your docker-compose.yml. Configured appropriately, you can use a volume to persist your backend data at the file system level regardless of how many times your backend service is restarted/rebuild/destroyed by docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any data to persist, then you can mount that data in volumes. Usage of volumes in docker can be understood from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes). For  wordpress, you can mount host directory in container's `/var/www/html/`. Following volume configuration should help you in this.

```
volumes:
  - ./html/:/var/www/html/
```

**Tip 1:** If you want few things to be already installed in your image, install then in the dockerfile itself and create your own custom image. [Build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) should help you in using a dockerfile in your `docker-compose.yml`.

**Tip 2:** To give you a better understanding of how you can do local development in docker, I'll suggest you use your dockerfile for this purpose.

In dockerfile, you can use `RUN` command for installing anything. And output of each RUN command gets stored in *cache*. So once you have successfully built your image then next  `RUN` command would not get executed but instead its *cache* will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Under the service volumes You can use the following syntax:

```
host:container
```

Example:

```
wordpress:

  volumes:

      -../html:/var/www/html
```

Specify an absolute path mapping

```
/opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Path on the host, relative to the Compose file

```
./cache:/tmp/cache
```

User-relative path

```
~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro
```

Named volume

```
datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```